# react apex charts x axis labels and tool tip showing different times instead of actual PST time

Tags: reactjs, datetime, utc, apexcharts, pst

i am new to react js and

i am using react apex charts of **chart type line** and getting the data from backend in the form of json array and coming to the issue the data has time as key in **UTC** iso format and my web server/application time format is PST. for that i am converting to PST before feeding to the chart.

but instead of pst time chart giving other times as labels i am tried to check conversion but unable to find the issue.

this is my code:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import ReactApexChart from 'react-apexcharts';

const Dashboard = () => {
  const [last24HoursStats, setLast24HoursStats] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      try {
        const jsonData = '[{"voiceCount":10,"smsCount":15,"updatedTime":null,"updatedTimeAsString":"2024-03-27T15:00:00Z"},{"voiceCount":5,"smsCount":5,"updatedTime":null,"updatedTimeAsString":"2024-03-27T14:00:00Z"}]';
        const jsonObject = JSON.parse(jsonData);
        if (jsonObject) {
          setLast24HoursStats(jsonObject);
        }
        last24HoursStats.map(item => {
          const pstTimeString = formatToPSTByDate(item.updatedTimeAsString);
          alert("UTC " + item.updatedTimeAsString + " GMT " + new Date(pstTimeString) + " PST " + pstTimeString);
        });
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error fetching data:", error);
      }
    };

    fetchData();
  }, [last24HoursStats]);

  const formatToPSTByDate = (utcDate) => {
    const date = new Date(utcDate);
    const options = {
      weekday: 'short',
      year: 'numeric',
      month: 'short',
      day: 'numeric',
      hour: 'numeric',
      minute: 'numeric',
      second: 'numeric',
      hour12: false,
      timeZone: 'America/Los_Angeles',
    };
    const formattedDate = date.toLocaleString('en-US', options);
    return formattedDate.replace(/,/g, '');
  }

  const transformedData = [
    {
      name: 'Voice',
      data: last24HoursStats.map(item => {
        const timestamp = new Date(formatToPSTByDate(item.updatedTimeAsString)).getTime();
        const count = item.voiceCount;
        return [timestamp, count];
      })
    },
    {
      name: 'SMS',
      data: last24HoursStats.map(item => {
        const timestamp = new Date(formatToPSTByDate(item.updatedTimeAsString)).getTime();
        const count = item.smsCount;
        return [timestamp, count];
      })
    }
  ];

  const last24HoursStatsChart = {
    series: transformedData.map(item => ({
      name: item.name,
      data: item.data,
    })),
    svOptions: {
      chart: {
        type: 'line',
        toolbar: {
          export: {
            csv: {
              filename: 'hourlyReqActivity',
              columnDelimiter: ';',
              headerCategory: 'Timestamp',
              dateFormatter: function (timestamp) {
                return new Date(timestamp);
              }
            },
            svg: {
              filename: 'ReqActivity',
            },
            png: {
              filename: 'ReqActivity',
            }
          },
        },
      },
      colors: ['#FFA500', '#0000FF'],
      dataLabels: {
        enabled: false,
      },
      stroke: {
        curve: 'smooth',
      },
      fill: {
        type: 'none',
      },
      legend: {
        show: true,
        position: 'bottom',
        horizontalAlign: 'center',
        offsetY: 8,
        markers: {
          width: 15,
          height: 15,
          radius: 2,
        },
        itemMargin: {
          horizontal: 10,
        },
      },
      xaxis: {
        type: 'datetime',
      },
      title: {
        text: 'Request Activity',
        align: 'center',
        style: {
          fontSize: '18px',
          fontWeight: 'bold',
          color: '#333',
        },
      },
    },
  };

  return (
    <div className="dashboard_lineChart">
      <ReactApexChart options={last24HoursStatsChart.svOptions} series={last24HoursStatsChart.series} type="line" height={300} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default Dashboard;
```

for the above data i am getting this conversion prints properly

```
UTC 2024-03-27T15:00:00Z GMT Wed Mar 27 2024 08:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time) PST 3/27/2024, 8:00:00 AM
UTC 2024-03-27T14:00:00Z GMT Wed Mar 27 2024 07:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time) PST 3/27/2024, 7:00:00 AM
```

but not getting why instead of plotting at 7 AM and 8:00 AM plotting at 1 : 00 AM and 3:00 AM of Mar 27

please help me how to get correct x axis labels and as well as tool tip not displaying proper x axis label

Thanks.